# IOS black screen huge problemm

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, screen

I have a huge problem when i terminate my app. After i restart it everything becomes inactive. And when i push the home button a black screen appears.It works fine in the simulator.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: all i have there is UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem that might be related, so I hope this helps...

If you are running in the debugger and you push the home button, restarting it from the launcher instead of the debugger may get the system into knots. If this is the case, hitting the stop button on the debugger should un-gum the works.

Comment: Thaks a lot.That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you're terminating the app using the home button?

I've found that doing that in both Simulator and Device makes the OS start behaving oddly and sometimes resulting in a blank screen, especially on the device. It is something to do with backgrounding and what I've found is that you need to explicitly terminate the app using the "Stop" menu option in the Debugging/Product menu (depending on Xcode 3 or 4)